# AJAX is not being called

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm having an issue with AJAX as for some reason it either isn't being called or isn't working

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#my_form").submit(function(event) {
    alert("submited");

    event.preventDefault("#my_form");

    var post_url = $(this).attr("action"); //get form action url
    var request_method = $(this).attr("method"); //get form GET/POST method
    var form_data = $(this).serialize(); //Encode form elements for submission

    alert(post_url + "" + request_method + " " + form_data);

    $.ajax({
      type: post_url,
      url: request_method,
      data: form_data,
      success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
        $("server-results").html(data);
      }
    });

    $('#loadingDiv').hide().ajaxStart(function() {
      $(this).show();
    });
    //.ajaxStop(function() {
    //  $(this).hide();
    //});
  });
});
```

I've debugged as much as I could and there is no issue with the form function being activated in JavaScript or the 3 variables being transported into the JS code block. However ajaxStart doesn't activate which makes me believe that the problem is with just ajax.

I also checked the link to ajax and it seems to be working however I'm not sure if its the right link or if it's not valid for whatever reason.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

FYI the ajax link is at the top of the page above both HTML and JS.

Comment: Can you use `beforeSend` and `complete` to hide and show the div

Comment: **$("server-results").html(data);** here you have not specified if **server-results** is a class or id and therefore the output of the server will never be printed on the page

Answer (score 2):

You have passed wrong parameters:

```
type: post_url,
url: request_method,
```

You need to pass post_url in url and request_method in type. Just change it to:

```
type: request_method,
url: post_url,
```

Comment: Also include that `$("server-results").html(data);` does not specify the selector correctly as id or class

Comment: using global ajaxstart is not a good option unless you want to trigger the same loading text for every ajax call

Comment: I can't believe I missed that but I corrected it and still, nothing is happening. It's like ajax itself isn't being called. BTW $("server-results").html(data); isn't the main issue because in that case, I would at least be getting the alert.

Answer (score 2):

**$("server-results").html(data);** here you have not specified if **server-results** is a class or id and therefore the output of the server will never be printed on the page

[jQuery .ajaxStart()](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/)

As reported in jQuery's official documentation, the ajaxStart event can not be activated by the #loadingDiv element, but you must use the document.

```
$( document ).ajaxStart(function() {
  $( ".log" ).text( "Triggered ajaxStart handler." );
});
```

Summing up the code should be something like this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#my_form").submit(function(event) {
    alert("submited");

    event.preventDefault("#my_form");

    var post_url = $(this).attr("action"); //get form action url
    var request_method = $(this).attr("method"); //get form GET/POST method
    var form_data = $(this).serialize(); //Encode form elements for submission

    alert(post_url + "" + request_method + " " + form_data);

    $.ajax({
      type: post_url,
      url: request_method,
      data: form_data,
      success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
        $(".server-results").html(data);
      }
    });

    $(document).ajaxStart(function() {
      $('#loadingDiv').show();
    });
    .ajaxStop(function() {
      $('#loadingDiv').hide();
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I believe the answer may be a combination of both yours **and** Bhumi Shah's answers. There appears to be multiple issues to address.

Comment: I had identified the bug before I reported it in the comments of the question